# Will a Factory Reset on an unlocked Samsung S2 4G T989 from T-Mobile relock the phone?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, factory-reset, sim-unlocking

I have a Samsung S2 4G T989 from T-Mobile which is unlocked. It is currently using ion Indian carrier.

I want to Factory Reset it. Will it be locked again after performing a reset? I don't have any code with me.

Answer (score 0):

NO. A Factory Reset does not re-lock your phone.

Answer (score -1):

No because efs files will not be updated by factory reset